# What type of Lambda event should I use to handle a SNS message received from an SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-net

I have an SNS topic that I publish an SNS message to. I have an SQS queue subscribed to it, that in turns triggers a Lambda function.

Based on [this documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html), I should receive a notification similar to this:

```json
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "MessageId": "63a3f6b6-d533-4a47-aef9-fcf5cf758c76",
  "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic",
  "Subject": "Testing publish to subscribed queues",
  "Message": "Hello world!",
  "Timestamp": "2012-03-29T05:12:16.901Z",
  "SignatureVersion": "1",
  "Signature": "EXAMPLEnTrFPa3...",
  "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic:c7fe3a54-ab0e-4ec2-88e0-db410a0f2bee"
}
```

I currently have this:

```
public string FunctionHandler(SNSEvent sns, ILambdaContext context)
```

`SNSEvent` doesn't match the message coming through.

What event type should I use in my Lambda function signature?

Comment: What type authentication you are using?  You may need to request a token.  Then use token with the query.

Comment: I am on IAM and an IAM role. I am not sure I fully understand the relevance though?

Comment: See picture : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/access-aws-services-from-an-asp-net-core-app-using-amazon-cognito-identity-pools.html

Comment: @jdweng I don't see how the authentication is in any way related to the shape of the Lambda event object.

Comment: @Spikee you are receiving SQS messages, so the even tis definitely going to be an SQS event. Inside that event, the list of messages will contain SNS message objects.

Comment: SNS is a HTTP Request.  See : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html

Comment: @jdweng That has no link, please refrain from adding comments that can further confuse other readers.

Answer (score 1):

When SNS sends a message to an SQS queue, **it wraps the original message in an SQS message envelope**, which includes additional metadata such as the message ID, receipt handle, and message attributes.

Therefore, when you subscribe an SQS queue to an SNS topic and then configure the SQS queue to trigger a Lambda function, **the function will receive a SQS event; it won't receive an SNS event**.

What you're seeing in the docs is the SNS message that is passed to SQS and not the wrapped SQS message that you need to handle in your function.

Here's the format of the wrapped message - note the original SNS message (as shown in the docs) is set within the `Body` field.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "MessageId": "76c57c14-985c-4f96-911a-0998b849ad80",
      "ReceiptHandle": "xxx",
      "Body": "{\n  \"Type\" : \"Notification\",\n  \"MessageId\" : \"7006b0c3-0a57-5df3-95da-edb8af971e0a\",\n  \"TopicArn\" : \"arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:585470346692:topic\",\n  \"Subject\" : \"subject 2\",\n  \"Message\" : \"message 2\",\n  \"Timestamp\" : \"2023-09-13T11:56:48.310Z\",\n  \"SignatureVersion\" : \"1\",\n  \"Signature\" : \"xxxx",\n  \"SigningCertURL\" : \"https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-xxx.pem\",\n  \"UnsubscribeURL\" : \"xxx\"\n}",
      "Md5OfBody": "4f2c093ce9ca18e634e56d2d01df1338",
      "Md5OfMessageAttributes": null,
      "EventSourceArn": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:xxx:queue",
      "EventSource": "aws:sqs",
      "AwsRegion": "eu-west-1",
      "Attributes": {
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "5",
        "AWSTraceHeader": "Root=1-6501a380-a2d7b7a2f246bc50f981003f;Sampled=1",
        "SentTimestamp": "1694606208339",
        "SenderId": "AIDAISMY7JYY5F7RTT6AO",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1694606208339"
      },
      "MessageAttributes": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

To handle this, you need to use the predefined `SQSEvent` class, from the [`AWS.Lambda.SQSEvents`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents) Nuget package. You can then extract the SNS message(s) from the SQS message envelope(s).

Here's a fully-working example Lambda I wrote, that should work:

```cs
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.SNSEvents;
using Amazon.Lambda.SQSEvents;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace SnsToSqsToLambda;

public class Function
{
    public async Task FunctionHandler(SQSEvent sqsEvent, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        foreach (var message in sqsEvent.Records)
        {
            var snsMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SNSEvent.SNSMessage>(message.Body);
            await ProcessEventAsync(snsMessage, context);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessEventAsync(SNSEvent.SNSMessage snsMessage, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine($"Subject: {snsMessage.Subject}");
        context.Logger.LogLine($"Message: {snsMessage.Message}");
    }
}
```

Test data:

```bash
aws sns publish \
    --topic-arn 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxx:topic' \
    --subject "subject 1" \
    --message "message 1"
```

```bash
aws sns publish \
    --region 'region' \
    --topic-arn 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxx:topic' \
    --subject "subject 2" \
    --message "message 2"
```

CloudWatch output:

```
info Subject: subject 1 
info Message: message 1
```

```
info Subject: subject 2
info Message: message 2
```